# How do I manually code "Run Document" for an interactive shiny knitr/r markdown doc?

Tags: r, rstudio, render, knitr, r-markdown

I've created an interactive knitr/r markdown doc with embedded shiny apps.

To view the final output this code generates, I usually click the "Run Document" button in RStudio.

However, I'm wondering: **how would I manually code "Run Document" in my script**?

- In other words, **is there a function that runs the document to generate the final interactive shiny doc?**

I tried rmarkdown::render('file_name.Rmd'), but this seems to just create a file named `file.name.html` with just a mess of unformatted code (no actual "pretty" finalized output).

So how do I do this??

Answer (score 1):

Found it.

```
rmarkdown::run
```

More info [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/rmarkdown/versions/1.3/topics/run)